# Disable automounting of hard disks on ubuntu live

Tags: boot, hard-drive, live-usb, automount

I have an ubuntu live USB.  When I try to boot it on a computer with a SATA hard disk, it automounts the hard disk and that would seem to corrupt the windows 7 installation which is on the hard disk.

I do not want to mount the hard disk, i just need to hit a few dd commands on it...

Is there any way I could configure the Ubuntu live OS to not automount hard disks at startup ?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a really old question, but maybe this can still help someone.

What works (tested on Ubuntu 18.04.1 live USB) is to manually add `systemd.mask=udisks2` to the kernel commandline, either via directly editing the live image, or via GRUB commandline editor.

Sources:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170549/how-to-disable-automount-for-external-devices-in-opensuse-13-2
- https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/kernel-command-line.html